# Rally Ruby API - add new line character to the 'description' field

Tags: ruby, api, rally

I am using Ruby API to create user stories. I need to set 'description' field to a multi-line string. But it seems that Rally is not recognizing `\n` or `\r\n`. I tried RTF `\line` as well. What is the proper way to encode new-line and other special characters for Rally ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try using `<br>` - that's worked for me with Rally rich text fields.

Comment: it works. thank you very much. ex: "line 1<br>line 2"

Answer (score 1):

It's the same for C#.
`<br>` + string + `</br>`